# Duality between necessity and possibility?

Tags: modal-logic

Is there any system of modal logic in which the duality between necessity and possibility does not hold? In other words, is there any system of modal logic in which

$\Box p = \neg\Diamond\neg p$ and $\Diamond p = \neg\Box\neg p$

does not hold?

Comment: Yes: [Intuitionistic modal logic](https://www.slideshare.net/valeria.depaiva/intuitionistic)

Comment: See also Alex Simpson, [The Proof Theory and Semantics of Intuitionistic Modal Logic](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/als/Research/thesis.pdf).